# Using PowerShell script below, how to check the SSL certificate validity?

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting, active-directory, windows-scripting

I need to modify the script below, so I can get the list of AD server and then check for any SSL certificate that is in the server for its validity.

Note: The server may or not may run IIS, which is why I am not sure how to do it properly.

```
$ComputerName = Get-ADComputer -Filter {Enabled -eq $True} -SearchBase "OU=Servers,OU=Production,DC=Domain,DC=com"
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
    [parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline)][string[]]$ComputerName,
    [int]$TCPPort = 443,
    [int]$Timeoutms = 3000
)

process {
    foreach ($computer in $computerName) {
        $port = $TCPPort
        write-verbose "$computer`: Connecting on port $port"
        [Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = {$true}
        $req = [Net.HttpWebRequest]::Create("https://$computer`:$port/")
        $req.Timeout = $Timeoutms
        try {$req.GetResponse() | Out-Null} catch {write-error "Couldn't connect to $computer on port $port"; continue}
        if (!($req.ServicePoint.Certificate)) {write-error "No Certificate returned on $computer"; continue}
        $certinfo = $req.ServicePoint.Certificate

        $returnobj = [ordered]@{
            ComputerName = $computer;
            Port         = $port;
            Subject      = $certinfo.Subject;
            Thumbprint   = $certinfo.GetCertHashString();
            Issuer       = $certinfo.Issuer;
            SerialNumber = $certinfo.GetSerialNumberString();
            Issued       = [DateTime]$certinfo.GetEffectiveDateString();
            Expires      = [DateTime]$certinfo.GetExpirationDateString();
        }

        new-object PSCustomObject -Property $returnobj
    }
}
```

Comment: What issues are you having with this script?

Comment: This is the error: $ComputerName = Get-ADComputer -Filter {Enabled -eq $True} -SearchBas ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token '$ComputerName' in expression or statement.

Comment: from what i can tell, you cannot have ANY code ahead of the `[CmdletBinding()]` line. you have a `process` block ... that line looks like it otta be the 1st thing in the `process` block OR in the `begin` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you've forgotten to put the function instantiation on top or not, but the following should be the correct format for an advanced function in PowerShell. You can also give the parameter ***$ComputerName*** a default value with the ***Get-ADComputer*** cmdlet. Try this out to see if this works.

```
function Get-ADComputerCert {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [int]$TCPPort = 443,
        [int]$Timeoutms = 3000
    )

    process {
        $ComputerName = (Get-ADComputer -Filter {Enabled -eq $True} -SearchBase "OU=Servers,OU=Production,DC=Domain,DC=com").Name
        foreach ($computer in $computerName) {
            $port = $TCPPort
            write-verbose "$computer`: Connecting on port $port"
            [Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = {$true}
            $req = [Net.HttpWebRequest]::Create("https://$computer`:$port/")
            $req.Timeout = $Timeoutms
            try {$req.GetResponse() | Out-Null} catch {write-error "Couldn't connect to $computer on port $port"; continue}
            if (!($req.ServicePoint.Certificate)) {write-error "No Certificate returned on $computer"; continue}
            $certinfo = $req.ServicePoint.Certificate

            $returnobj = [ordered]@{
                ComputerName = $computer;
                Port         = $port;
                Subject      = $certinfo.Subject;
                Thumbprint   = $certinfo.GetCertHashString();
                Issuer       = $certinfo.Issuer;
                SerialNumber = $certinfo.GetSerialNumberString();
                Issued       = [DateTime]$certinfo.GetEffectiveDateString();
                Expires      = [DateTime]$certinfo.GetExpirationDateString();
            }

            new-object PSCustomObject -Property $returnobj
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Still not working Peter.
At line:4 char:75
+ ... meter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline)][string[]]$ComputerName = Get-ADC ...
+                                                                  ~
Missing expression after '='.

Comment: @SeniorSystemsEngineer try to remove the [string[]] identifier on the parameter. Since get-adcomputer retrieves objects, not strings.

Comment: @SeniorSystemsEngineer Also, you might need to evaluate the Get-ADComputer as PowerShell is barking at you for not having a complete expression after the $ComputerName. To do that, just enclose the Cmdlet and it’s parameters in parentheses.

Comment: I already have a function written to do this, which reads the SSL stream using tcpclient class instead so will get certificate details from any IP or FQDN. You could simply pipe get-adcomputer results to it. If you want to take a look I can post here or on my blog for you

Comment: @SeniorSystemsEngineer I just updated my answer and fixed the $ComputerName variable to get the name value string. This should work now.